# Update the properties of a Data Extension through SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud

Here is my use case:

We have 1000+ data extensions in a BU. They currently do not have data retention set up. I want to create a SSJS script to create filters to retrieve the data extensions and update the retention period programmatically.

I can retrieve the data extensions. I was unable to find a way to update the attributes of the data extension.

Any help is appreciated.

-Best, Monomit

Comment: Have you looked into API? Might be easier to do it that way

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find a REST endpoint to update the DE, if you are aware of any, please let me know.

Comment: Not possible with REST, but see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Do it using SOAP API:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/changing_the_retention_period_for_a_data_extension.htm

Of if it’s easier for you to work with JavaScript, you can use WSProxy to make the SOAP call:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_create.htm